# For MS Access lock file (.laccdb), what does locked in `determine which records are locked` mean?

Tags: ms-access

> The ".laccdb" or ".ldb" file is used to determine which records are
> locked in a shared database and by whom.

1. What does the word **locked** in `determine which records are locked` mean?
2. In other words - when does a record get locked?
3. For example: Assuming the lock file indicates that Record 10 is locked, then does it mean that someone else is reading that particular record or writing that particular record or both?

Comment: I think it depends on the application Client Settings > Advanced > Default Record Locking.

Answer (score 1):

Well, this is kind of a broad subject.

We have many levels of locking. Let's go from least to most specific:

- An exclusive database lock: The entire database is locked, used when working with application objects such as forms, reports and VBA modules. Also when a user manually requests an exclusive lock.

  Exclusive locks don't actually need the .laccdb file, they can just use a normal file lock. When working with the database part of an accdb file (e.g. ODBC/OLEDB) these are never set afaik.
- Table write locks: A user is editing the structure of a table, for example by adding and removing a column, or changing a column type.

  The entire table can't be read to or from while a user holds this lock.
- Page write locks: Records go on pages, and the entire page a certain record is on is locked. This happens mainly when users is editing or intending to edit records on encrypted databases,  since when writing to a record on an encrypted database, the entire page needs to be rewritten.

  Depending on what you're doing, you may or may not be able to read from locked pages, but you certainly can't write to them.
- A record write lock: A user is either editing or intending to edit a specific record. Behaves mostly identical to a page lock, but only for a single record instead of a page of records.
- A table read lock: Prevents others from setting a table write lock, set when reading a table (by opening it, opening a bound report form, or querying it)

Documentation on this is not great in Access, so I might've missed some.

There are lots of things that influence locks, such as the recordset type and record locks property on forms, on recordsets the recordset type and LockEdits property, and on the database the database properties.